# What does "something are down" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this picture on the Net...

[image]

What does "The computers are down" mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literally, ***"computers are down"*** means that those computers are off-line, usually because of some kinds of problems (such as power failure, software failure, operating system crash, etc.).

I don't know if there are any deeper meaning. But it seems to me that the comic hints that people nowadays rely too much on computers. Even a guru still needs computers to provide a good answer. (In this case, *"the meaning of life".*)

---

PS. This reminds me of a novel by Douglas Adams, *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*. In order to get ***"the answer to life, the universe, and everything"***, a supreme being had to create a computer to provide such an answer. After a long time past, the computer gave the answer, **42**. (The computer that was created in the story was actually our Earth, including us human beings.)

Comment: +1 for the reference to HHGG.